# How to Replace Multiple Strings to a Single String

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a character vector comprising:

`male, maLe, Male, MALE, ma8le` characters. I want to replace the above with `"Male"` How to do this in R

I tried 'sub', 'gsub', 'str_replace'. The solution must be Similar to python given below:

```
df['gender'].replace(["male", "maLe", "Male", "MALE", "ma8le"], ["Male","Male","Male","Male","Male"], inplace = True)
```

I need to perform the same in R

```
gend_cor<- c("male", "maLe", "Male", "MALE", "ma8le")

data$gender <- gsub(gend_cor, "Male", data$gender)
```

My expected output is If I enter the above "gend_cor", it must return Male instead of the other wrong words

Comment: `gsub(paste0(gend_cor, collapse = "|"), "Male", data$gender)`

Comment: You can try `replace`, i.e. `df$Gender <- repalce(df$gender, df$gender %in% gend_cor, 'Male')`